# Magento: Hide Msrp price if is logged specify customer group

Tags: php, magento

Is possible hide in Magento msrp price if is logged specify customer group?

We have this in our template:

> ```
> <?php if ($_product->getMsrp()): ?>
> <?php $_msrpPrice = $this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getMsrp(),true,true) ?>
> <p class="beznacena">
> <span ><?php echo $this->__('Manufacture price:'); ?><?php echo $_msrpPrice ?></span>
> </p> <?php endif; ?>
> ```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to find logged in user group ID then use if else in template to hide prices.

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
      // Get group Id
      $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
      //Get customer Group name
      $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
      echo $group->getCode();
}
```